# Unknown Error in Python when solving a matrix using a custom class

Tags: python, matrix

I wrote a class to represent a matrix in python, and the many different operations that can be performed on it. For the most part, it works, but every once in a while I'll get a specific error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Philip\Documents\Coding\Python\matrix_testing.py", line 30, in     <module>
        b.rref()
      File "c:\python27\lib\matrix.py", line 193, in rref
        copy[ i ] = self._rowAdd( self._rowMultiply( copy[ id ], -copy[ i ][ pivot_column ] ), copy[ i ] )
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

This is unusual, and I'm unsure how I could arrive at a NoneType index. Inserting print statements does nothing to explain.
Here's one type of matrix that reproduces that error:

```
b = [
            [ 1, -2, -3, 6, -2 ],
            [ 0, 0, 1, -1, -3 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, -5 ],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        ]

b = Matrix( b )
b.addColumn( [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] )
b.show()
b.rref()
b.show()
```

And here's the matrix class:

```
class MatrixError(Exception):
    '''
    Base class for handling errors
    '''
    pass

class InvalidMatrix(MatrixError):
    '''
    For handling errors with invalid matrix sizes.

    Attributes:
        msg -- Error message
        m -- row count
        n -- column count
    '''
    # def __init__( self, msg, m, n ):
        # self.msg = msg
        # self.m = m
        # self.n = n
    pass    
class NonMatrixObject( MatrixError ):
    '''
    For handling operations on non-matrices.

    Attributes:
        msg -- Error message
        invalidType -- Type of incorrect object
    '''
    '''
    def __init__( self, msg, invalidType ):
        self.msg = msg
        self.invalidType = invalidType
    '''
    pass
class Matrix:
    '''
    This class is used to make a representation of a matrix, on which different operations can be performed, such as matrix addition, subtraction, and multiplication,
    as well as solutions to the reduced row matrix, and row matrix forms.
    '''
    def __init__( self, initMatrix = [] ):
        ''' Check if matrix is valid size. If valid, sets matrix.'''
        valid = True
        if len( initMatrix ) != 0:
            for i in range( len( initMatrix ) ):
                curr = len( initMatrix[ i ] )
                prev = len( initMatrix[ i - 1 ] )
                if i != 0:
                    if ( curr != prev ) or ( prev  == 0 ):
                        valid = False
                        break

        if valid:
            self._matrix = initMatrix
            self._m = len( initMatrix )
            if self._m == 0:
                self._n = 0
            else:
                self._n = len( initMatrix[ 0 ] )
        else:

            try:
                raise InvalidMatrix( 'Error: Length of rows inconsistent, ', prev, curr )
            except InvalidMatrix as e:
                print( '%s matrix contains a row of length %d and of length %d' % ( e.msg, e.m, e.n ) )

    # Matrix generation
    def generateMatrix( self, m, n, v ):
        '''Generates an m*n matrix with all values as v'''
        temp = []
        for i in range( m ):
            tempRow = []
            for i2 in range( n ):
                tempRow.append( v )
            temp.append( tempRow )

        self._matrix = temp

    def identityMatrix( self, n ):
        '''Generates the n identity matrix'''
        iMatrix = []
        self._m = n
        self._n = n
        for i in range( n ):
            row = []
            for u in range( n ):
                if u == i:
                    row.append( 1 )
                else:
                    row.append( 0 )
            iMatrix.append( row )
        self._matrix = iMatrix

    # Methods for solving RRE form and RE form
    def _rowAdd( self, row1, row2 ):
        '''Internal use: adds one row to another'''
        for i, amount in enumerate( row2 ):
            row1[ i ] += amount
        return row1

    def _rowDivide( self, row, divisor ):
        '''Internal use: divides a row by a value'''
        row = [ ( float( value ) / divisor ) for value in row ]
        #print( row )
        return row

    def _rowMultiply( self, row, factor ):
        '''Internal use: multiplies a row by a factor'''
        row = [ ( value * factor ) for value in row ]
        return row

    def _isInRE( self, row = None ):
        '''Internal use: checks if matrix is in eow echelon form. Broken currently'''
        if row and ( row in range( len( self._matrix ) ) ):
            copy = [ self._matrix[ row ] ]
        else:
            copy = self._matrix

        verdict = True
        for i, value in enumerate( copy ):
            for i2, value2 in enumerate( value ):
                if ( i2 == i ) and ( value2 != 1 ):
                    verdict = False
                elif ( i2 < i ) and ( value2 != 0 ):
                    verdict = False

        return verdict

    def isInRRE( self ):
        pass

    def _findPivot( self, row ):
        '''Internal use: finds the column id of the pivot position in a row'''
        for id, value in enumerate( row ):
            if value != 0:
                return id
        return None


    def _checkBlank( self, row ):
        '''Internal use: checks if a row is blank'''
        for value in row:
            if value != 0:
                return False
        return True

    # Solving

    def ref( self ):
        '''Converts matrix to row echelon form'''
        if self._n >= self._m:

            copy = self._matrix
            copy.sort()
            copy.reverse()

            for id in range( len( copy ) ):
                pivot_column = self._findPivot( copy[ id ] )
                if pivot_column == None:
                    continue
                pivot = copy[ id ][ pivot_column ]
                copy[ id ] = self._rowDivide( copy[ id ], pivot )
                for i in range( id + 1, len( copy ) ):
                    if not self._checkBlank( copy[ i ] ):
                        addend = self._rowMultiply( copy[ id ], -copy[ i ][ pivot_column ] )
                        copy[ i ] = self._rowAdd( addend , copy[ i ] )

            copy.sort()
            copy.reverse()
            self._matrix = copy
        else:
            try:
                raise InvalidMatrix( 'Error: cannot convert matrix, ', self._m, self._n )
            except InvalidMatrix as e:
                print( '%s%dX%d is invalid size' % ( e.msg, e.m, e.n ) )

    def rref( self ):
        '''Converts matrix to reduced row echelon form'''
        if not self._n >= self._m:
            try:
                raise InvalidMatrix( 'Error: cannot convert matrix, ', self._m, self._n )               
            except InvalidMatrix as e:
                print( '%s%dX%d is invalid size' % ( e.msg, e.m, e.n ) )
        else:
            self.ref()
            copy = self._matrix
            for id in reversed( range( len( copy ) ) ):
                pivot_column = self._findPivot( copy[ id ] )
                if not pivot_column:
                    pass

                for i in reversed( range( id ) ):
                    if not self._checkBlank( copy[ i ] ):
                        copy[ i ] = self._rowAdd( self._rowMultiply( copy[ id ], -copy[ i ][ pivot_column ] ), copy[ i ] )

            self._matrix = copy

    def solve( self ):
        '''Solves and returns x in the formula Ax=b.'''
        copy = Matrix( self._matrix )
        if copy._m + 1 == copy._n:
            copy.rref()
            answ = []
            for row in copy._matrix:
                answ.append( row[ -1 ] )
            return answ

    # Methods for outside matrix use
    def factorMultiply( self, factor ):
        if type( factor ) is int:
            new = []
            for row in self._matrix:
                new.append( self._rowMultiply( row, factor ) )
            self._matrix = new

    def addRow( self, row ):
        '''Adds a row to the matrix'''
        if len( row ) == self._n:
            self._matrix.append( row )
        else:
            try:
                raise InvalidMatrix( 'Error: Row is not correct size', row, self._n )
            except InvalidMatrix as e:
                print( '%s (%d).' % ( e.msg, e.n ) )

    def addColumn( self, column ):
        if len( column ) == self._m:
            for i in range( self._m ):
                self._matrix[ i ].append( column[ i ] )

    def display( self ):
        '''Displays full value of matrix'''
        for row in self._matrix:
            print( row )
        print( '\n' )

    def show( self ):
        '''Displays value of matrix rounded to 2 decimal places'''
        for row in self._matrix:
            printed = '[  '
            for value in row:
                if value == 0:
                    printed += '0.00  '
                else:
                    printed += '%0.2f  ' % value
            print( printed + '  ]' )

    def augment( self, other ):
        new = self._matrix
        if other._m == self._m:
            for i in range( self._m ):
                new[ i ] = self._matrix[ i ] + other._matrix[ i ]
        self._matrix = new

    # Overloading operators
    def __add__( self, other ):
        try:
            dupe = self._matrix
            if ( self._n == other._n ) and ( self._m == other._m ):
                for i in range( self._m ):
                    for id, amount in enumerate( other._matrix[ i ] ):
                        dupe[ i ][ id ] += amount

            return Matrix( dupe )
        except:
            raise( NonMatrixObject( 'Error: Cannot add matrix object with non-matrix type ', type( other ) ) )

    def __mul__( self, other ):
        try:
            if self._n == other._m:
                new = []
                for i in range( self._m ):
                    row = []
                    for i2 in range( other._n ):
                        sum = 0
                        for i3 in range( self._n ):
                            factor1 = self._matrix[ i ][ i3 ]
                            factor2 = other._matrix[ i3 ][ i2 ]
                            addend = factor1 * factor2
                            sum += addend
                        row.append( sum )
                    new.append( row )
                return Matrix( new )
            else:
                raise InvalidMatrix( 'Matrix sizes are not compatible for multiplication' )
        except:
            raise NonMatrixObject( 'Cannot multiply matrix object with non-matrix type \'%s\'' % type( other ) )
```

Comment: Hmm ... Well, from the looks of it, `i`, `pivot_column` or `id` is `None`.  Maybe some print statements to figure out which are in order :-).  (Or using the debugger . . .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in rref you call `_findPivot` which can return None. You then check if `pivot_column` is None and if it is you `pass`. But in Python, the pass keyword does nothing. The error happens when you try to access `copy[ i ][ pivot_column ]`.
Did you intend to use `continue` to skip the iteration instead of pass?